# Convert mixed datetime to a unified format in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a tabe like this:

| date |
| --- |
| 1/1/2020 |
| 2022-01-01 |

How do I unify my date column and convert anything to '2022-01-01'. I have tried convert function in SQL but it failed.... gave me an error:

> converting date/time from string failed

Comment: So you are storing your dates as strings?

Comment: @Dale K it's my companys data someone set that field as string...

Comment: @RedSus You have a **sacred duty** to _make them suffer_ now, because thanks to their poor DB design choices we all now (in this SO thread, at least) have to suffer through dates-as-text.

Comment: If you have an error message, it is expected that you would also post the corresponding code. In this case it might be a simple syntax issue, the specific functions and arguments that use to convert the values is very important. You need to include a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The general advice is to make sure your schema uses a *Date Typed* column to store the information, not a character based column. That way your application is forced to enter the data in the correct format.

> **[Date and time data types and functions (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)**

Rather than manipulating the data on every read, if the data is stored in a standard format, queries against that data will be far more efficient even if the data is not indexed, but especially if it is.

- The specifics to this with regard to *Date and Time* values are important to understand but outside of the scope of this post. It makes sense though to process and sanitise the data inputs once during the *write* operation instead of for *every read* operation, using appropriate data types is the first step in designing an efficient SQL data schema.

But if we have to, you can use `CAST`, it might be important to filter out the values that will cause the cast to raise an exception:

```
WITH StringDates as (
    SELECT '1/1/2020' as [Date]
    UNION 
    SELECT '2022-01-01'
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Not valid'
)
SELECT [Date], ISDATE([Date]) as IsDate, Cast([Date] as Date) as TypedDate
FROM StringDates
WHERE ISDate([Date]) = 1
```

| DateString | IsDate | TypedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2022-01-01 |

You can use the same logic to do this conditionally in a set:

```
WITH StringDates as (
    SELECT '1/1/2020' as [Date]
    UNION 
    SELECT '2022-01-01'
    UNION 
    SELECT 'Not valid'
)
SELECT [Date]
     , ISDATE([Date]) AS IsDate
     , CASE WHEN ISDATE([Date]) = 1 THEN Cast([Date] as Date) END AS TypedDate
FROM StringDates
```

| DateString | IsDate | TypedDate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 2022-01-01 |
| Not valid | 0 | NULL |

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is the `TRY_CONVERT` function with an appropriate [date and time style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles). Note, that the result from this conversion is usually ambiguous (what date is `05/06/2020` for example), so you need to define the style precedence.

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES
   ('1/1/2020'),
   ('2022-01-01'),
   ('13/13/2020'),
   ('5/6/2020')
) v ([Date])
```

Statement:

```
SELECT 
   DateAsText = d.Date, 
   DateAsDate = (
      SELECT TOP 1 TRY_CONVERT(date, d.Date, v.Style) 
      FROM (VALUES (1, 103), (2, 23)) v (Precedence, Style)
      WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, d.Date, v.Style) IS NOT NULL
      ORDER BY v.Precedence
   )  
FROM Data d
```

Result:

| DateAsText | DateAsDate |
| --- | --- |
| 1/1/2020 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2022-01-01 | 2022-01-01 |
| 13/13/2020 | null |
| 5/6/2020 | 2020-06-05 |