# convert different string date formats from single column to one form of output in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have one date columns as varchar datatype which has multiple date formats. I have to convert all different formats into one date format as 'YYYY-MM-DD'.
I am trying to convert it but couldn't make it. Below are different formats available in column.

**Input**

```
8/15/2022
15-Aug-22
15/08/2022
```

**Required Output**

```
2022-08-15
```

Comment: The real problem here is your design, and that you are using a `varchar` to store date (and time) values; there are multiple [date and time data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#DateandTimeDataTypes) and there is no excuse to *not* be using one. Unfortunately for you, it's very likely that much of your data as lost meaning. For example, if you have the value `'01/12/2021'` is that 1 December 2021 or 12 January 2021? How do you know, and *more importantly* how would SQL Server know?

Comment: I answered the similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73656155/convert-mixed-datetime-to-a-unified-format-in-sql/73658152#73658152). You need to check all possible date and time styles, but the conversion can be ambiguous (what date is `05/06/2002` for example).

Comment: Hi @Zhorov, Thanks for your reply. In your previous post for one of the output is showing as blank. But I want as date. I have given a try with TRY_CAST. This is giving the same result, but it is giving NULL values for dd/mm/yyyy formats

Comment: The fact that you have values that are in `dd/mm/yyyy` when in your example have one that is clearly in `mm/dd/yyyy` just further cements my point that you have no idea what some of your dates are meant to be.

Comment: As the comments above already try to tell you, there is NO 100% solution for this, because for some formats it is impossible to know the correct date, `04/05/2022` for example. So the link of Shorov might seem helpfull to you, but it will not give you a full proof solution. As Larnu already said, much of your data is lost because of that same reason. You will keep hitting problems, the only solution for you is to bite the bullet and fix the design, use one of the many date datetimes that are available in the database

Comment: @kathija, simply use 101, 103 and 106 for date and time [styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles). But, again, converting date and time values from text, usually returns ambiguous results.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think you need to take the pessimistic approach here and assume that, possibly for a lot of your data, you don't know what the value is *meant* to be. As I stated in the comments, if you have the value `'01/12/2021'` is that 1 December 2021 or 12 January 2021, how do you know, and *more importantly* how would SQL Server know? As such, for dates like this you *don't* know and therefore the value `NULL` is more appropriate that a guess.

Here I use 3 different formats, an implicit one, and then 2 explicit ones (`MM/dd/yyyy` and `dd/MM/yyyy`) Then I check if the `MIN` and `MAX` values match (`NULL` values are ignored for aggregation), and if they do return that value. If they don't then `NULL`, as what value the date is is ambiguous and therefore intentionally shown as an unknown value (`NULL`):

You can, if needed, add more styles to the below, but this should be enough for you to work with.

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ID int IDENTITY(1,1), --I assume you have a unique identifier
                            StringDate varchar(20));

INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (StringDate)
VALUES('8/15/2022'), --Must be M/d/yyyy
      ('15-Aug-22'),
      ('15/08/2022'), --Must be dd/MM/yyyy
      ('12/01/2021'); --Could be MM/dd/yyyy or dd/MM/yyyy
GO

SELECT YT.ID,
       YT.StringDate,
       CASE MAX(V.SomeDate) WHEN MIN(V.SomeDate) THEN MAX(V.SomeDate) END AS DateDate
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(TRY_CONVERT(date,YT.StringDate)), --Implicit conversion
                        (TRY_CONVERT(date,YT.StringDate,101)), --US style MM/dd/yyyy
                        (TRY_CONVERT(date,YT.StringDate,103)))V(SomeDate) --UK style dd/MM/yyyy
GROUP BY YT.ID,
         YT.StringDate;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yifIm8k1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of TRY_CONVERT and REPLACE function in a CASE operator to do so.

As an example :

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(STR_DATE VARCHAR(32));

INSERT INTO @T VALUES
('8/15/2022'),
('15-Aug-22'),
('15/08/2022');

SELECT CASE
          WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DATE, STR_DATE, 101) IS NOT NULL
             THEN CONVERT(DATE, STR_DATE, 101)
          WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DATE, REPLACE(STR_DATE, '-', ' '), 6)  IS NOT NULL
             THEN CONVERT(DATE, REPLACE(STR_DATE, '-', ' '), 6)
          WHEN TRY_CONVERT(DATE, STR_DATE, 103)  IS NOT NULL
             THEN CONVERT(DATE, STR_DATE, 103)
       END
FROM   @T
```